# Using INI_SET within a PHP page

Tags: php

If I use `ini_set('default_socket_timeout',30);` within a `PHP` page, will this affect **all** socket calls made on the server or just those on this pages current lifetime?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only in current script call.

See [PHP ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

Comment: Lovely thank you, I thought I read it right but wasn't too sure!

Answer (score 4):

As the PHP manual page says :

> The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Seems you've been fully baked :)

Answer (score 2):

Just those made during the request using that script.

All other requests will use the defaults in the php.ini file